# Jquery :: How to able disabled onclick button when input isn't empty anymore?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have some problem with my Jquery function. I wanna disable button #next if the fields of form are empty and able it if fields aren't empty anymore... But #next doesn't change when fields isn't empty...
Some help for me ? :/ Thank's !

```
$(function () {
    $('#next').prop("disabled", true).css({
        "background-color": "#424242",
        "cursor": "default"
    });
    if ($('.idinput').val() != '') {
        $('#next').prop("disabled", false).css({
            "background-color": "#1C1C1C",
            "cursor": "pointer"
        });
        $('#next').click(function () {
            $('#regdiv').animate({
                left: "-=400"
            }, 2000, function () {
                $('#next').prop("disabled", true).css({
                    "background-color": "#424242",
                    "cursor": "default"
                });
                $('#class').show("slide", {
                    direction: "left"
                }, 1500);
            });
        });
    } else {
        $('#next').prop("disabled", true).css({
            "background-color": "#424242",
            "cursor": "default"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Where's your HTML form?

Comment: I searched how to do it... Just an noob I am.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is executed only once during the page onload event.

You need to check if the fields are empty/not on blur event, or bind the event to the last element of the form. When the user fills the last element of the form, check the previous fields if they are empty or not and based on that you can enable the button.

Assuming, this is the last element of the form:

```
$(".idinput").blur(function() {
    if ($('.idinput').val() != '') {
        $('#next').prop("disabled", false).css({
            "background-color": "#1C1C1C",
            "cursor": "pointer"
        });
        $('#next').click(function () {
            $('#regdiv').animate({
                left: "-=400"
            }, 2000, function () {
                $('#next').prop("disabled", true).css({
                    "background-color": "#424242",
                    "cursor": "default"
                });
                $('#class').show("slide", {
                    direction: "left"
                }, 1500);
            });
        });
    } else {
        $('#next').prop("disabled", true).css({
            "background-color": "#424242",
            "cursor": "default"
        });
    }
});
```

Hope, this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can clean up your code by using css instead of applying styles in jQuery.

```
#next{
    background-color: #1C1C1C;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#next[disabled]{
    background-color: #424242;
    cursor: default;
}
```

And here is a way to do it in jQuery.

```
$(function(){
    $('.idinput').on('input',function(){
        $('#next').prop("disabled", $('.idinput').val() == '');
    });

    $('#next').click(function(){
        $('#regdiv').animate({left: "-=400"}, 2000, function(){
            $('#next').prop("disabled", true);
            $('#class').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1500);
        });
    });
});
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo